# What is an example that a function is differentiable but derivative is not Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I have two questions that i'm curious about.

1. If $f$ is differentiable real function on its domain, then $f'$ is Riemann integrable.
2. If $g$ is a real function with intermediate value property, then $g$ is Riemann integrable.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Hints:

1) The function $f$ defined by $$f(x)=\cases{ x^2\sin(1/x^2),&$x\ne0$ \cr 0,&$x=0$}$$ is differentiable on $[-1,1]$; but its derivative is unbounded on $[-1,1]$.

2) Derivatives enjoy the Intermediate Value Property (by [Darboux's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29)).

Comment: Note that one can verify that $f'$, with $f$ is as above, has the Intermediate Value Property directly, rather than appealing to Darboux.

Comment: I am sorry, but on (1) the derivative is not integrable? Thank you. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate_0%5E1+%28+2+x+sin%281%2Fx%5E2%29+-+%282+cos%281%2Fx%5E2%29%29%2Fx%29

Comment: @Quiet_waters WA is computing an improper integral. The derivative here is not Riemann integrable (such functions are bounded).

Comment: Thank you so much. Maybe you could help me on this question. Thank you! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4125797/seeking-an-example-of-continuous-function-that-has-no-integrable-derivative

Answer (score 21):

1. A Riemann integrable function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$ must be bounded on that interval. So if you take $$f(x)=\cases{x^{\frac{3}{2}} \sin(\frac{1}{x}),&$x\ne0$ \cr 0,&$x=0$}$$ on $[0,1]$, you can check that this is a continuous and differentiable function but with an unbounded derivative and so it is not integrable. You can even construct an example of a differentiable function whose derivative is bounded but is still not Riemann integrable - see [Volterra's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra's_function).
2. Again, you take a function such as $$f(x)=\cases{\frac{1}{x} \sin(\frac{1}{x}),&$x\ne0$ \cr 0,&$x=0$}$$ on $[0,1]$. This is a discontinuous, unbounded function that satisfies the intermediate value property, but not Riemann integrable. A bounded example is given by the derivative of Volterra's function.

Comment: I am sorry, but in (1) the derivative is not integrable? Thank you in advance https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate_0%5E1+%7B%28-2+cos%281%2Fx%29+%2B+3+x+sin%281%2Fx%29%29%2F%282+sqrt%28x%29%29%7D.

Comment: @Quiet_waters: The derivative of $(1)$ is not bounded so the derivative is not **Riemann integrable**. Wolfram alpha computes the integral as an **improper integral** which is something different.

Comment: Thank you so much. Maybe you could help me on this question. Thank you! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4125797/seeking-an-example-of-continuous-function-that-has-no-integrable-derivative

Answer (score 7):

From the two examples provided above, it turns out that the desired function $f$ is chosen in such a way that $f'$ is unbounded. However, turning a function $f$ into unbounded $f'$ is somewhat not interesting. If you really want to look for an example of $f$ such that $f'$ is defined and bounded everywhere, the [Volterra function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) is what you are looking for. This function is defined by making use of the [Smith–Volterra–Cantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) set and "copies" of the function defined by
$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& x^2 \sin ⁡ \frac 1x & & \text{for } x\neq 0 \\
& 0 & & \text{for } x=0.
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
The first three steps in the construction of Volterra's function are as in the picture below.

[image]