# Does the integral of the derivative of a piecewise continuous function stitch it together?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Say we have a piecewise continuous* function $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$. Consider $g(x)\equiv \int_a^x \frac{df(x')}{dx'}dx'$. The integral $g$ is continuous as far as I know from Riemann integration. So is $g$ the uniquely "stitched together" version of $f$?

The same question in other words: if I began with a continuous function $g$ and added distinct constants $c_i$ to it on intervals $[a_i,a_{i+1}]$, I would have $f$. Then does $\int_a^x \frac{df(x')}{dx'}dx'$ recover $g$?

*edit: I meant to imply differentiable, as Martin pointed out. I leave it unaltered for generality.

Comment: Piecewise derivable, you mean.

Comment: Even more required:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257069/what-is-an-example-that-a-function-is-differentiable-but-derivative-is-not-riema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** $f'$ exists and is integrable, yes and yes. $f$ and $f + $ a piecewise constant function will have the same derivative in almost everywhere point.