# Class of Riemann integrable functions with antiderivative

Tags: real-analysis, integration

We know that continuous functions

- are Riemann integrable and
- have an antiderivative.

Are there any other (hopefully huge :-) function classes fulfilling both of these properties?

Comment: By Darboux theorem, any such function has to obey the intermediate value property. I am not certain whether this goes the other way though. A good example is the discontinuous $2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$ which has antiderivative $x^2\sin(1/x)$. Both should equal $0$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Also interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257069/what-is-an-example-that-a-function-is-differentiable-but-derivative-is-not-riema

Comment: Any such function can't have a jump discontinuity. But I am not sure if a function possesses an anti-derivative if it has discontinuities of oscillatory type.