# Example of function that is not Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis

What example can be given for a $f\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb R$, differentiable at all points of the segment $[0,1]$ and such that $f'$ is not Riemann integrable by $[0,1]$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question ?

Comment: It's not exactly trivial: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257069/what-is-an-example-that-a-function-is-differentiable-but-derivative-is-not-riema).

Comment: My thoughts is only to use Lebesgue criteria, but I don't know how to exactly

Comment: The link to the *Volterra function* is the right advice.  The key to the construction is to know that there is a fat Cantor set (i.e., a perfect, nowhere dense subset $P$ of $[0,1]$ that does not have measure zero).   The idea is to set $f(x)=0$ on $P$ and adjust the "humps" on the complementary intervals so that $f'$ is discontinuous at points of $P$.  I don't see this as a homework problem, more something worth researching.